# ETH Staking & Pooling

Tags: proof-of-stake

I have ETH and I am building a portfolio.

How will I be able to stake my ETH holdings and make sure these are safe?

Can someone please provide some guidance? Thanks

Comment: The public ethereum chain still relies on Proof of Work - Proof of Stake hasn't been implemented yet so unless I've misunderstood the question you can't stake ether yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staking isn't on the mainnet yet, and it'll likely be at least 6 months until Casper FFG is deployed. When it is deployed, pools will likely popup that allow you to (with an amount of trust) deposit your eth to the pool. If you don't want to use a pool, you can solo stake, but you'll need a fairly substantial amount of ETH for that to be profitable.